# sql LIKE query only returns exact match, not similar matches

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a `$wpdb` query to search for items in the media library. The search kind of works, except it only returns exact matches.

I have two images in the library, one called `run` and the other called `running`, if I search just `run`, it only returns the exact match, `running` isn't returned. Am I missing something here? I thought `LIKE` returned things that contains those characters?

Here's my query in full, I'm using AJAX to stick it into the page.

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb;

if( isset($_GET['nameLike']) ) {
    $search = $_GET['nameLike'];
} else {
    $search = '';
}

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'inherit' AND post_title LIKE %s", $search), ARRAY_A);

foreach ($results as $result) : ?>

    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $result[ID], array(200, 150) ); ?>

    <div class="grid-1-4"><?php echo($image); ?></div>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: `LIKE '%SEARCH TERM%'` Place `%` before and after search term.

Comment: If I do this I get no results at all. My search term is variable based on what a user types into a text `input`. In the `wpdb` docs is says to write the syntax as I have (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: Added as answer to match your WP use-case. My previous comment was related to pure MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote answer in the comment, I'll write here also how to implement it properly in WP. You can add '%' in your search term.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'inherit' AND post_title LIKE %s", '%' . like_escape($search) . '%'), ARRAY_A);
```

EDIT: Taken WP example from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/how-do-you-properly-prepare-a-like-sql-statement)

Comment: Here at 2021 this helped me, if anyones needs to query more than one word, e.g: "A V C", you need to surround each one of them to make the query work for similar words, "%A% %V% %C%".